# Getting ORA-00904:invalid identifier error while executing a procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, procedures

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CONCAT_BLOB(A in BLOB,B in BLOB) RETURN BLOB IS
 C BLOB;
BEGIN
DBMS_LOB.APPEND (C,A);
DBMS_LOB.APPEND (C,B);
RETURN C;
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_NEW_REC_tmp is 


 tempBlob BLOB :=utl_raw.cast_to_raw('^');

  begin 

  execute immediate  'update audt set new_rec= CONCAT_BLOB(tempBlob,new_rec)' ;
    commit;

    end;
```

exec update_NEW_REC_tmp;

while executing the procedure getting an error:ORA-00904: "TEMPBLOB": invalid identifier

Comment: Why do use dynamic SQL ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use binding variables in your anonymous statement:

```
update audt set new_rec= CONCAT_BLOB(tempBlob,new_rec)
```

tempBlob and new_rec variables are out of scope.

I think you can helpful Oracle Documentation: [click here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg09dyn.htm)

Comment: when using binding variablesm, I am getting an error ORA-01008: not all variables bound